# All my files under C:\ are gone

Tags: windows-10

I am using Windows 10 Pro on my laptop. Last night I turned off my laptop (proper shutdown) and today when I started it, the post boot showed up preparing Windows.

After I logged into my Windows everything was gone. It's just like a new installation.

However, the software which I installed for example : VLC, Google Chrome, FireFox, IDM are still intact but all their settings like:  bookmarks, save password, history, etc are gone (guess it didn't overwrite ProgramFiles)

- My Windows Update is turned off. As I always defer Updates. So no point of Automatic Update.
- No files under `C:\Users` as sometimes Windows keeps the old user and their files during/after installation
- No Windows.old directory present under `C:\`
- The files are not hidden. I checked the hidden item box from view tab.

What can be the cause of it ? Any Ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: Have files been hidden? Can you use Restore Point? Can you give a little more detail on what is missing 'browsers missing but apps installed are still there? - internet explorer gone?, it's part of windows, what history, libraries gone or not.

Comment: Sounds like it lost the user profile & built a new one. Nothing should actually be *gone* - Does this help - https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/88903fce-9722-4774-9390-02adfeb84e46/windows-7-user-profile-lost-when-you-log-off-or-reboot?forum=w7itproui ? If so, we can turn it into an answer.

Comment: @mic84 - I have edited my question and added more details.

Comment: @Tetsujin. Thanks buddy. That did the trick. I have answered the fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just followed this [link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/88903fce-9722-4774-9390-02adfeb84e46/windows-7-user-profile-lost-when-you-log-off-or-reboot?forum=w7itproui) which stated :

> 1. Restart your PC to release the locks on your profile.
> 2. Log on with another administrative account
> 3. Delete C:\Users\%username%
> 4. Delete C:\Users\TEMP
> 5. Delete the registry key matching your SID from  "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows 
>      NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList". Check the value "ProfileImagePath" to
>      make sure you pick your own profile.
> 6. Restart once again.

Just because I am the solely user/administrator of my PC. Instead of following each and every step. I just removed `C:\Users\Temp` and restarted my PC.

And Windows picked up my original profile. And all my settings are back :)

Comment: I'd edit & include the full method from the link, just in case the link ever disappears.

Comment: @Tetsujin sure. Instead I am going to delete my answer and you answer the post.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with answering yourself at all - in fact it's encouraged. Just copy/paste the 'full' fix over to here, add a citation [which your link just about does] & all is good.

Comment: Please read [How to reference material written by others](https://superuser.com/help/referencing). You should block quote text that has been written by some else. See [Markdown help](https://superuser.com/editing-help). I've fixed it for you this time, but please pay attention to this in future.